# PHP mail corrupted attachment

Tags: php

I have a form to send form with attachments to email.

It works fine to send files to gmail adresses (on thunderbird client), but to adresses like @company.com on outlook, the attachements came corrupted.

This is what i have in header and body :

```
    //header
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "From:".$sender_email."\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$sender_email."" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n";

    //message text
    $body = "--$boundary\r\n";
    $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";
    $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($message));
```

Comment: You can use PHPMailer or SwiftMailer.

Comment: It's 2017 and some people still use `mail()`...

Comment: Any real help for this code please ?